# Does any printer proxy driver for Windows exist?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printing

What I need is to install a virtual "printer" device that will print a document sent to it using another printer in the system (specified in the settings).

There are a many virtual printers available to create PDF files but I couldn't find any that would be able to print the composed PDF (with another printer) automatically (without opening it in a PDF reader application) and remove the PDF file after this.

Do you happen to know about such a piece of software?

Extra functionality does not matter. The reason I need this is incompatibility of my actual printer driver with a particular use case (while virtual PDF printers work just fine in the same) and inapplicability of other solutions.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not there is already a solution to this but if not it is still possibly. I have used some called bullzip and that creates a PDF and saves it to a folder. You can set it so it has a predefined filename and folder. You can then create a fairly simple program (and run it in the background as a service) that can listen to a particular folder for pdf files and if one appears in there print it.

If nobody else knows of a program that does this automatically maybe this would be the way to go.

Comment: Nice idea, @RichardPowell. I actually use Bullzip PDF printer too. I consider it among the best of its kind and it's free.

Comment: Ivan, do you actually have adobe reader installed?

Comment: Of course I do, @RichardPowell. Do you know a single Windows user who doesn't? :-)

Comment: I don't have it installed. I use foxit reader :P

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a really old question - but I wonder if you ever found a solution or if the Bullzip PDF printer was your solution?

I'm also searching such a functionality - a virtual printer which does nothing else but forward all print jobs to another (configurable) printer in the system.
I want it to only provide one tray (which is then also forwarded to a specific configured tray of the real printer) so that the user is not able to choose a different one.

Does such a thing exist or do I have to write my own printer driver for this?
Of course nowadays it should also work at Windows 10 and 11, not only (but still) at Windows 7

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169426)